how 믿던 conjugated from 믿다？
I came across this sentence

믿던 사람들에게 사기를 당했다

I guess "믿던" comes from "믿다", but based on the verb conjugation rules I've learned, I can't understand how this change happened, or if it's a typo?

https://ko.dict.naver.com/#/entry/koko/b8bb3e0210fe4ca4aef64f77bbcf4f0a
"((동사의 어간 또는 어미 ‘-으시-’, ‘-었-’ 뒤에 붙어)) 앞말이 관형어 구실을 하게 하고 어떤 일이 과거에 완료되지 않고 중단되었다는 미완(未完)의 의미를 나타내는 어미."

According to the definition of '-던', -던 can be attached to a verb stem. Here, '믿' is the verb stem(동사의 어간).
If It feels awarkd, we could use "믿어 왔던 사람들에게 사기를 당했다" or "믿어 오던 사람들에게 사기를 당했다"
